# Can you grant privileges to an oracle cluster object?

Tags: oracle, privileges

I'm trying to allow an oracle user (userA) privileges to create a table on a cluster in another user's schema (userB). I can't find the relevant privilege to grant, and granting ALL PRIVILEGES on the cluster to userA complains that the table or view doesn't exist. Is what I'm trying to do possible? I also notice there isn't an ALL_CLU_COLUMNS dictionary table; is this related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

userA has to have the CREATE ANY TABLE privilege.  Be sure to qualify the userB schema for both the table and cluster object references.

So, using the emp/dept example from Oracle's docs:

userB:
CREATE CLUSTER emp_dept (deptno NUMBER(3));

userA:
CREATE TABLE userB.dept (
 deptno NUMBER(3) )
 CLUSTER userB.emp_dept (deptno);

Comment: Is it possible to do:

userA: CREATE TABLE userA.dept (deptno NUMBER(3)) CLUSTER userB.emp_dept(deptno) ?

Comment: In that case, how can I obtain column cluster information from the data dictionary? There isn't a ALL_CLU_COLUMNS dictionary table I can use, and USER_CLU_COLUMNS isn't available...

Comment: You have to use the dba_ view:
In this case: select * from dba_clu_columns where cluster_name like '%EMP%'

Comment: An additional note:  after thinking about it, the concept of an ALL_CLU_COLUMNS view doesn't make sense to me.  In the Oracle dictionary the ALL_% views are generally associated with objects on which a schema has privileges.  There are no direct object privileges associated with clusters in the Oracle security model - its more of a physical grouping and if anything should have a quota like tablespaces.